# AS 3 Action Script

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to get my EntityArray to stop moving once it hit's the screen width and height if anyone can help me it be great and then resets it's position to the centre it's for my university project

```
private function keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent)
{
    // Detect 'A' key for UP movement
    if(evt.keyCode == 65) 
    {
        trace("A")
        //Move player left (using key 'A')
       EntityArray[0].x = (EntityArray[0].x)-10;
    }

    //creating the Frog
    var newfrog = new frog();
    newfrog.x = 320;
    newfrog.y = 220;
    EntityArray.push(newfrog);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What about your current code isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put some pretty simple guard code in your `keyDownHandler`:

```
//Add the if statement after this line in your current function:  
EntityArray[0].x = (EntityArray[0].x)-10;

//Guard code
if (EntityArray[0].x <= 0) {
    EntityArray[0].x = 320;
} else if (EntityArray[0].x > Stage.width - EntityArray[0].width) {
    //Note:  You need to subtract the frog's width from the stage to avoid having the frog be mostly off the screen before resetting the position.
    EntityArray[0].x = 320;
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian thanks for this code added the code and had this error

Comment: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property Width through a reference with static type Class.

1119: Access of possibly undefined property Width through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: @GamesUK My bad, it should be 'width' with a lower-case w.

Comment: no problem how can i do it for -x 

       //if the frog reaches the edge of the screen 
   //it resets it's position
  if (EntityArray[0].x <= 0) {
   EntityArray[0].x = 300;
   }
   
   if (EntityArray[0].y <= 0) {
   EntityArray[0].y = 0;
   }

Comment: Hi Brian many thanks for the help one more

how can I spread out an array on the X axis I have a var loop that populates 3 items and need it to be spread out on the X position 
   // created a heart 
   for(var h:int=1; h<5; h++){
      trace(h);
   EntityArray.push(newHeart);
   EntityArray.x = (30,60,70);
   EntityArray.push(newHeart);
   newHeart.y = 20;
   trace("heart Created")
   }

Comment: @GamesUK I'd say that's worth posting as a separate question :)